# Git Push To Remote Server Hangs Using Cygwin

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin

I'm new to git via the command line and have run into a bit of trouble I haven't been able to pull myself out of.

I've set up a repository on my server and have created a local directory using the directions at [thelucid.com](http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/).

on server:

```
ssh git@example.com
mkdir my_project.git
cd my_project.git
git init --bare
git update-server-info # If planning to serve via HTTP
exit
```

then, on local machine:

```
cd my_project
git init
git add *
git commit -m "My initial commit message"
git remote add origin git@example.com:my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

When I get to the final command here "git push -u origin master" the command hangs and hangs and never stops hanging.

git status on local gives me this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

git status on the server (inside myproject.git/)gives me:

```
$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I'm not exactly sure where to look next, I've tried a bunch of things, but my ignorance is mountainous and I could use a guide; maybe a wizard, some dwarves, and hobbit if you have any spares. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on windows 8.1.
Using Cygwin

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Windows, [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/) is a better option. Using `git push` in Cygwin is known to have issues. The gist of it is that Git by default, tries to use a "simple password prompt" as part of its user authentication process, as mentioned in the `git-config` [doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)(search for `core.askpass`). This password prompt, however, only works on real UNIX, but not on Cygwin. If interested, you can read about the history of this issue [here](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/85).

If you absolutely have to use Cygwin, then make sure you installed the Cygwin git packages as specified [here](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=818). Then try run this command:

`$ git config --global core.askpass /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass`

There are probably other more involved solutions out there, but I think the simplest solution is still to install msysgit. :-)

Comment: It seems using Git Bash (which I assume is msysgit), solved the problem. I didn't need to change the directory I was in and git push went through just fine. Magic!

Thanks all! 
Cheers.
ie

Comment: Hello! Sorry about that. I would have accepted it earlier, but I am full of noob and didn't realize quite how to do so.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are inside the .git folder.
you need to be in the root folder (the parent of .git) to be able to view the status and then push all your changes.

```
cd..
git status
```